# Azure data factory V2 Azure ML batch processing

Tags: azure, machine-learning, azure-data-factory

I have tried to create ADF pipe line by invoking azure ML batch processing but i am not able to find to azure ML batch processing tasks. Can anyone help me on how can i use AZURE ML Batch process in AZURE DATA FACTORY V2 ?

Answer (score 0):

The BatchExecution activity is designed for invoking ML batch processing tasks. Hope below doc helps:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/transform-data-using-machine-learning

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response but when i try to create Pipeline using Azure Data Factory UI i am not able to find Azure ML batch activity in blade .

Answer (score 0):

You can now consider using Azure machine learning Execute Pipeline activity in Azure data factory to execute AML pipelines for batch ML tasks.
Also, if a pipeline endpoint ID is provided is provided as the 'Machine learning pipeline ID' type, then the Azure data factory pipeline will not need to be re-deployed even if a new machine learning pipeline is published in the AML workspace.

References:

1. [Execute AML pipelines in ADF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/transform-data-machine-learning-service)
2. [Create a versioned pipeline endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/v1/how-to-deploy-pipelines#create-a-versioned-pipeline-endpoint)